# Proguard not respecting -keeppackages parameter

Tags: java, jar, bytecode, proguard

I've got a package that uses introspection extensively.

There is a public class Binding, with a package-private inner class OneWayBinding. This is being obfuscated by ProGuard. I'd like to prevent it from being obfuscated, by specifying the entire package name. However, ProGuard seems to be obfuscating it anyway.

```
-keeppackagenames com.mypackage.binding
```

When I run my app I get this:

```
3/30/12 9:50:19.630 AM [0x0-0x276276].com.apple.JarLauncher: Caused by: 
    java.beans.IntrospectionException: No property exists with name: 
    origin for class com.mypackage.binding.Binding$OneWayBinding
```

Is this a bug in ProGuard? Is there some other option I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--keeppackagenames` only preserves the name of the package -- not the name of any classes in the package.  Use `--keepname` to preserve class names.